# Run Word Macro in a C # or VBA VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto

Today I have the following macro in Word

```
Sub comparedocs()
Dim arq1 As String
Dim arq2 As String
Dim itmDocProp As DocumentProperty

For Each prop In ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
    If prop.Name = "OrPath" Then
        arq1 = prop.Value
    ElseIf prop.Name = "NewPath" Then
        arq2 = prop.Value
    End If
Next

If arq1 = "" Or arq2 = "" Then
    MsgBox "Não encontramos as propiedades necessarias"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wrd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

MsgBox arq2
MsgBox arq1

'wrd.Documents.Open arq2
'wrd.Documents.Open arq1

'Application.CompareDocuments OriginalDocument:=Documents(arq1), RevisedDocument:=Documents(arq2), _
'Destination:=wdCompareDestinationOriginal, Granularity:= _
'    wdGranularityWordLevel, CompareFormatting:=False, CompareCaseChanges:= _
'    True, CompareWhitespace:=False, CompareTables:=True, CompareHeaders:=True _
'    , CompareFootnotes:=True, CompareTextboxes:=True, CompareFields:=True, _
'    CompareComments:=True, CompareMoves:=True, RevisedAuthor:="Autor", _
'    IgnoreAllComparisonWarnings:=False
'ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
' ActiveWindow.ShowSourceDocuments = wdShowSourceDocumentsBoth
End Sub
```

I need to insert this macro into my Word VSTO supplement and run it when the user clicks the button, below is the code I'm trying to run, but it works only when the macro already exists in word I would like to insert the macro together with the supplement as it will be installed for several customers

```
 public void OnTableButton(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        RunMacro(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application, new object[] { "comparedocs" });
    }

    private void RunMacro(object oApp, object[] oRunArgs)
    {
        oApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Run",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null, oApp, oRunArgs);
    }
```

Comment: please remove the `wordpress` tag, you probably only wanted `word`

Comment: Thanks Dennis, can you help me with my question?

Comment: sorry, unfortunately not, this is not really my area of expertise

Comment: If you are already in a Word VSTO it should be a trivial task to write the c# equivalent of the VBA code.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I'm trying this now, but I'll need to insert macro at some point, because our customers use macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starter for 10

```
public void OnTableButton(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            //RunMacro(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application, new object[] { "comparedocs" });
            comparedocs();
        }
        void comparedocs()
        {
            string arq1 = "";
            string arq2 = "";
            //Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty ItmDocProp;

            foreach (var prop in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties)
            {
                if (prop.Name == "OrPath")
                {
                    arq1 = prop.Value;
                }

                else if (prop.Name == "NewPath")
                {
                    arq2 = prop.Value;
                }
            }

            if (arq1 == "" || arq2 == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não encontramos as propiedades necessarias");
                return;
            }

            var wrd = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

            MessageBox.Show(arq2);
            MessageBox.Show(arq1);

            ////wrd.Documents.Open arq2
            //'wrd.Documents.Open arq1

            //'Application.CompareDocuments OriginalDocument:=Documents(arq1), RevisedDocument:=Documents(arq2), _
            //'Destination:=wdCompareDestinationOriginal, Granularity:= _
            //'    wdGranularityWordLevel, CompareFormatting:=False, CompareCaseChanges:= _
            //'    True, CompareWhitespace:=False, CompareTables:=True, CompareHeaders:=True _
            //'    , CompareFootnotes:=True, CompareTextboxes:=True, CompareFields:=True, _
            //'    CompareComments:=True, CompareMoves:=True, RevisedAuthor:="Autor", _
            //'    IgnoreAllComparisonWarnings:=False
            //'ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
            //' ActiveWindow.ShowSourceDocuments = wdShowSourceDocumentsBoth
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @freeflow